# What to change in BufferedQuery.php?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was trying to import a file which is 1.35GB to a MySQL database and recieved this error:

> Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql-parser\src\Utils\BufferedQuery.php on line 202

I have tried other methods that including adding

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

to config.inc.php but it didn't work

Comment: You cannot upload anything to phpMyAdmin as `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP to simplify maintaining a MySQL database

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using it to run a query to store and use a .sql file

Comment: You really should not use phpmyadmin to execute an sql file over 1GB! The file upload and script execution is done in a standard http request - response cycle, which is expected to run for a few seconds, perhaps for a few minutes. Such a big file would require the cycle for run for hours. Upload the sql file separately to the server and use a local client (e.g. cli) to import the sql file.

Comment: @Shadow I have separated the file to 139 pieces but they all ended up causing errors

Comment: @PoltEmreT and what do you expect us to do about unspecified errors?

Answer (score -1):

You should compress your file first and then upload it. Because phpMyAdmin also supports gzip,zip etc formats. This will increase uploading speed.

Comment: The file is already compressed, it was 4.35GB before compression

Comment: did you restarted apache after changing those configurations?

Comment: Yes, I tried it multiple times